# Redirect root to folder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following project structure:

```
/app
    /api
    /css
    /img
    /js
```

I want to redirect all the requests from `/app` folder to the sub folder `/api`. I tried the following **.htaccess** code, without success:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /api/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My Apache has Mod_Rewrite enabled. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in `/api/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteRule ^((?!api/index\.php/).+)$ api/index.php/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: This won't redirect, it will just silently rewrite without changing URL in browser. What URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: ```http://app/```, but I think I'm doing it wrong. I need a page redirect, not a URL rewrite.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/app/$ /app/api`

Comment: `RedirectMatch` doesn't need `RewriteEngine On` and that will work from `DocumentRoot` not from `/api/.htaccess` file